# How does HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name work? and how secure is it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis

I am using *HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name* to get the user name of the logged in user. I would like to know how this is working (using NTLM v2 / Kerberos) and how secure is it? Can the user try to mimic he is someone else?

Basically, from a security point of view, is there something I should be worried about, or how should I improve it?

Comment: You can be absolutely sure about it! Once user is authenticated (and it's where there _may_ be security issues) then that property is completely safe to use. What you can improve/choose is authentication method, password strength, http (non -s) sniffing and stuff like that.

Comment: @Adriano - My applications are using HTTPS. The authentication method is done only at Windows Login, and not something about the application, is this correct?

Are there any microsoft references about this issue?

Comment: Do you use Windows Authentication? Well it should be safe enough (and the weak part is the password used by Windows' users to login). Do not worry about User.Identity at all, it's safe. Security issues will more easily come from code we write (and passwords users will choose) than from "infrastructure" and well tested code.

Comment: @Adriano - Is 'HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name' an example of Integrated Windows Authentication? Because that is what I am using for Windows Authentication on the application. From an Active Directory Authentication point of view, we should be using that, yes!

Comment: No, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is always that, regardless what kind of authentication you use.

Comment: @Adriano Ok, then this should be secure! Since by default it runs on NTLM. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, your users will be more unsafe than your application.

Comment: Who a user is and how they authenticate are two separate issues ntlm x.509 certificates and web forms are part of the identification and authentication process current user identity is reported by the system after successful authentication is completed.  Secure the protocol with https and ssl certificates of at least 1024 bits to prevent traffic sniffing and ntlm for intra domain connections will be secure

Comment: Insightful link with plenty of detail: http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#ntlmHttpAuthentication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are authenticating using Windows authentication (which, given your mention of NTLM/Kerberos it appears you are) then what happens is (roughly) as follows

- IE sends a request with no authentication header to your web server.
- IIS refuses the request with a 401 response code and tells the browser the authentication scheme it wants (in this case Negotiate, which tries Kerberos first, and then falls back to NTLM)
- The kerb handshake takes place over multiple connections, and the ticket is validated against AD
- IIS passes the ticket down to ASP.NET which, in the process of building the Request object populates the principal on the thread assigned to the request with the identity details from the ticket.
- When you access HttpContext.User you see the principal for the current thread.

It's secure. It's basically the same authentication type used when you connect to a Windows server via file shares or anything else that is using kerberos. It's actually IIS and Windows itself doing the vast majority of the work, ASP.NET is just giving you a nice way to query the results.

Comment: Is User.Identity.Name just as secure when using Forms Authentication?

Comment: What is this "ticket" you mention? How easy is it for a user to spoof this ticket?